# CSS: Carousel returning to start after second image

Tags: html, css

**Problem**

I've developed a carousel which scrolls through 3 images. When it comes to move from the 2nd to 3rd it appears to quickly snap to the initial image before returning to the 3rd image. Can someone help me point out the mistake I have made?

[image]

```css
.carousel-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  width: 300%;
  animation: sliding 12s infinite;
}
.carousel div {
  width: 300%;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes sliding {
  30% {
    transform: translateX(0);
 }
  35% {
    --widthA: 100%;
    --widthB: calc(var(--widthA) / 3);
    --widthC: calc(var(--widthB) * -1);     
    transform: translateX(var(--widthC));
 }
  65% {
    --widthA: 100%;
    --widthB: calc(var(--widthA) / 3);
    --widthC: calc(var(--widthB) * -1);  
    transform: translateX(var(--widthC));
 }
  70% {
    --widthA: 100%;
    --widthB: calc(var(--widthA) / 3);
    --widthC: calc(var(--widthB) * 2); 
    --widthD: calc(var(--widthC) * -1); 
    transform: translateX(var(--widthD));
 }
  98% {
    --widthA: 100%;
    --widthB: calc(var(--widthA) / 3);
    --widthC: calc(var(--widthB) * 2); 
    --widthD: calc(var(--widthC) * -1); 
    transform: translateX(var(--widthD));
 }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="image-one" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000/000000?Text=Image1);"></div>
        <div class="image-two" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/100/00FF00/000000?Text=Image2);"></div>
        <div class="image-three" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000FF/000000?Text=Image3);"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why is there a 65% keyframe and suddenly 70% keyframe? Of course it would go back and forth.

Comment: @m4n0 I had just refactored this code https://codepen.io/januaryofmine/pen/wbOqEm

Comment: Why don't you just use the exact same code?

Comment: @m4n0 it has fixed widths, I want mine to be responsive.

Comment: It cannot be reproduced on Firefox but on Chrome.